# Unable to launch xdiagnose through GUI in normal way

Tags: gnome, executable, activities-overview, pkexec, xdiagnose

I am in need of doing some diagnostics work with `xdiagnose`, however when searching for it in the Activities Overview, and then clicking on it, absolutely nothing happens, when in the past it would ask me for my password so that I could run it as root.

I looked further into this and tried running it in Terminal, and this was the output from the command `xdiagnose`:

```
Error: Must run as superuser
```

So why is it simply not prompting me for the password in the GUI with `pkexec` as usual? I am able to run it with `pkexec xdiagnose` in Terminal, but how come it doesn't prompt for the password as usual in the GUI? Is this a bug?

**Information Update:**

As requested, there was no output from the command:

```
grep -r 'xdiagnose' ~/.local/share/applications
```

And the output of this command `grep -r 'xdiagnose' /usr/share/applications` was:

```
/usr/share/applications/xdiagnose.desktop:Name=xdiagnose
/usr/share/applications/xdiagnose.desktop:Exec=pkexec xdiagnose
/usr/share/applications/xdiagnose.desktop:Icon=/usr/share/xdiagnose/icons/microscope.svg
/usr/share/applications/xdiagnose.desktop:X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=xdiagnose
```

The contents of the file is this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=xdiagnose
GenericName=Diagnose Graphics Issues
Comment=X.org Diagnostic and Repair Utility
Exec=pkexec xdiagnose
Icon=/usr/share/xdiagnose/icons/microscope.svg
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=System;Settings;
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=xdiagnose
```

I have reinstalled it with `sudo apt-get install --reinstall xdiagnose`, however this seems to have made no difference at all to anything.

I have attempted to launch another application via the Activities Overview that uses `pkexec` to start, and it works fine as normal.

Another this is that when I made the `xdiagnose.desktop` file executable and ran it `xdiagnose` still didn't start and this was the output:

```
./xdiagnose.desktop: line 1: [Desktop: command not found
./xdiagnose.desktop: line 3: Graphics: command not found
./xdiagnose.desktop: line 4: Diagnostic: command not found
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/xdiagnose/applet.py:30: PyGIWarning: Gtk was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import Gtk
Error: Must run as superuser
./xdiagnose.desktop: line 9: Settings: command not found
./xdiagnose.desktop: line 10: X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=xdiagnose: command not found
```

---

**OS Information:**

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.10
Release:    15.10
Codename:   wily
Flavour: Gnome
Gnome Version: 3.18
```

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `grep -r 'xdiagnose' ~/.local/share/applications` and `grep -r 'xdiagnose' /usr/share/applications`

Comment: @A.B.: Ok, I have added the requested information.

Comment: Do you have two entries for xdiagnose in your activities?

Comment: @A.B.: No, I do not.

Comment: Can you start the application  with `pkexec xdiagnose` in a terminal?

Comment: @A.B.: Yes, I am able to launch it that way in Terminal successfully.

Comment: Just to double check, to be able to exclude another instance of a launcher runs instead: could you make the launcher in `/usr/share/applications`  executable and double click, see if it runs fine?

Comment: @JacobVlijm: I will now update my question with the information I have found.

Comment: @JacobVlijm: I have now updated my question with the information I think you asked for. You do mean to make the `xdiagnose.desktop` file executable and run it right?

Answer (score 1):

This is easy and functional, found it for me! :)

Replace the command application in your launcher
(/usr/share/applications/***yourapplication***.desktop)
with the follow:

```
 Exec=sh -c "pkexec command && true"
```

Example, this found it me:

In the terminal command put:

```
 sudo vim /usr/share/applications/xdiagnose.desktop
```

And edit the application.desktop that wish run as root

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=xdiagnose
GenericName=Diagnose Graphics Issues
Comment=X.org Diagnostic and Repair Utility
Exec=sh -c "pkexec xdiagnose && true"
Icon=/usr/share/xdiagnose/icons/microscope.svg
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=System;Settings;
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=xdiagnose
```

Hugs!

Comment: Tried this, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Either you have changed your desktop file `/usr/share/applications/xdiagnose.desktop` or you have an additionally desktop file in `~/.local/share/applications`

The originally content looks like this. Note the line **`Exec=`**

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=xdiagnose
GenericName=Diagnose Graphics Issues
Comment=X.org Diagnostic and Repair Utility
Exec=pkexec xdiagnose
Icon=/usr/share/xdiagnose/icons/microscope.svg
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=System;Settings;
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=xdiagnose
```

Use `pkexec xdiagnose` instead of `xdiagnose`, also in a terminal.

[image]

---

Ok, the problem seems not to be solved in that way, therefore a shot in the blue.

Reinstall the package again via

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xdiagnose
```

If that not help and as `pkexec xdiagnose` works in a terminal, create a bug report for GNOME shell:

```
ubuntu-bug xdiagnose
```

Comment: I have not changed that file, and it looks identical to the one you put up. There is also nothing associated with `xdiagnose` in `~/.local/share/applications`. So could this be a bug?